# Preprocess data in R

Tags: r

Im using R to create logistic regression classifier model.

Here is the code sample:

```
library(ROCR)
DATA_SET <- read.csv('E:/1.csv')

classOneCount= 4000
classZeroCount = 4000
sample.churn <- sample(which(DATA_SET$Class==1),classOneCount)
sample.nochurn <- sample(which(DATA_SET$Class==0),classZeroCount )

train.set <- DATA_SET[c(sample.churn,sample.nochurn),]
test.set  <- DATA_SET[c(-sample.churn,-sample.nochurn),]
full.logit <- glm(Class~., data = train.set, family = binomial)
```

And it works fine, but I would like to preprocess the data to see if it improves classification model.

What I would like to do would be to divide input vector variables which are continuoes into intervals. Lets say that one variable is height in centimeters in float.

Sample values of height:

183.23
173.43
163.53
153.63
193.27

and so on, and I would like to split it into lets say 3 different intervals: small, medium, large.

And do it with all variables from my set - there are 32 variables.

What's more I would like to see at the end correlation between value of the variables (this intervals) and classification result class.

Is this clear?

Thank you very much in advance

Comment: No, no, no, no, no you never bin continuous variables to include in a linear model unless absolutely necessary. The main reason is that you will lose information. Check [here](http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/wiki/Main/CatContinuous) for more info if you want. Correlation between categorical data is also tricky. You should really be using a contingency table instead. If you insist on using correlation make sure at least you use spearman's correlation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classification model creates some decision boundary and existing algorithms are rather good at estimating it. Let's assume that you have one variable - height - and linear decision boundary. Your algorithm can then decide between what values put decision boundary by estimating error on training set. If you perform quantization and create few intervals your algorithm have fewer places to put boundary(data loss). It will likely perform worse on such cropped dataset than on original one. It could help if your learning algorithm is suffering from high variance (is overfitting data) but then you could also try getting more training examples, use smaller set (subset) of features or use algorithm with regularization and increase regularization parameter

There are also many questions about how to choose number of intervals and how to divide data into them like: should all intervals be equally frequent or of equal width or most similar to each other inside each interval?

If you want just to experiment use some software like f.e. free version of [RapidMiner Studio](https://rapidminer.com) (it can read CSV and Excel files and have some quick quantization options) to convert your data